# Electron App Notarized but not opening. [electron-builder] [macOS Big Sur]

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-notarize

I successfully notarized the app and it gives the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lovT.png)

I checked the signing and notarizing and it gives me the following:

```sh
> pkgutil --check-signature ./path/to/app/XXXX.app
Package "XXX":
   Status: signed by a certificate trusted by macOS
   Certificate Chain:
    1. Developer ID Application: ...
```

and

```sh
> spctl -a -t exec -vvv ./path/to/app/XXXX.app
./path/to/app/XXXX.app: accepted
source=Notarized Developer ID
origin=Developer ID Application: XXXXXX (XXXXXX)
```

electron-notarize version is `^1.0.0`

This shows it is successfully notarized, here are my config files (and signing js file if that helps):

package.json

```json
"build": {
    "asar": true,
    "appId": "redacted",
    "files": [
      ...
    ],
    "afterSign": "./build/afterSignHook.js",
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "./build/resources"
    },
    "publish": [
      {
        "provider": "github",
        "owner": "redacted",
        "repo": "redacted"
      }
    ],
    "mac": {
      "category": "public.app-category.music",
      "icon": "assets/appIcons/DJFlame Logo.icns",
      "hardenedRuntime": true,
      "entitlements": "./build/resources/entitlements.mac.plist",
      "asarUnpack": "**/*.node"
    },
    "dmg": {
      "background": null,
      "icon": "assets/appIcons/DJFlame Logo.icns",
      "backgroundColor": "#202020",
      "window": {
        ...
      },
      "contents": [
        ...
      ]
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "perMachine": false,
      "installerIcon": "assets/appIcons/DJFlame Logo.ico",
      "license": "license.txt"
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": "AppImage",
      "icon": "assets/DJFlame Logo.png"
    }
  }
```

entitlements.mac.plist

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <array>
      <string>XXYYZZ112233.com.redacted.redacted</string>
    </array>

    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

afterSignHook.js (notarizing file)

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
var electron_notarize = require('electron-notarize');
const config = require('../package.json')
require('dotenv').config();
module.exports = async function (params) {
  // Only notarize the app on Mac OS only.  
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin' || path.join(params.appOutDir, `${params.packager.appInfo.productFilename}.app`) == '/Users/siddharth/dev/DJTorsten/dist/win-unpacked/DJFlame.app') {
    return;
  }
  // Same appId in electron-builder.  
  let appId = config.build.appId
  let appPath = path.join(params.appOutDir, `${params.packager.appInfo.productFilename}.app`);
  if (!fs.existsSync(appPath)) {
    throw new Error(`Cannot find application at: ${appPath}`);
  }
  const startNoteTime = new Date()
  console.log(`Notarizing ${appId} found at ${appPath}. Started Notarizing at ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}, expected max finish time ${new Date(new Date().getTime() + 300000).toLocaleTimeString()}`);
  try {
    await electron_notarize.notarize({
      appBundleId: appId,
      appPath: appPath,
      appleId: process.env.APPLE_ID, // this is your apple ID it should be stored in an .env file  
      appleIdPassword: process.env.APPLE_ID_PASSWORD, // this is NOT your apple ID password. You need to   
      //create an application specific password from https://appleid.apple.com under "security" you can generate  
      //such a password   
      //   ascProvider: process.env.appleIdProvider // this is only needed if you have multiple developer  
      // profiles linked to your apple ID.   
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw error;
  }
  console.log(`Done notarizing ${appId}! Time Finished: ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}, Time Elasped: ${Math.floor(new Date() / 1000) - Math.floor(startNoteTime / 1000)}s`);
};
```

**EDIT** I narrowed it down to the following lines:

```json
"afterSign": "./build/afterSignHook.js",
"directories": {
    "buildResources": "./build/resources"
},
...
"mac": {
    ...
    "hardenedRuntime": true,
    "entitlements": "./build/resources/entitlements.mac.plist",
    "asarUnpack": "**/*.node"
}
```

When I'm not getting that error, its also not notarized. I will edit the above snippet until I can find the exact cause of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a bunch of things to fix this, but I think that the following are the answer:

## #1 Add a value to package.json

When you add `"entitlements": "./build/resources/entitlements.mac.plist"`, add an inherit that points to the same file. Also add `gatekeeperAsses` to `false`. The code would look like

```json
"mac": {
      ...
      "hardenedRuntime": true,
      "gatekeeperAssess": false,
      "entitlements": "./build/resources/entitlements.mac.plist",
      "entitlementsInherit": "./build/resources/entitlements.mac.plist",
      "asarUnpack": "**/*.node"
}
```

## #2 Strip `entitlements.mac.plist` to bare-minimum

Apparently having too many entitlements may cause this error, so strip it to the entitlements you need. Mine would look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.audio-input</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```